# Итерационная обработка данных потоками

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, многопоточность

Суть программы в следующем:считать очередное число, обработка его первым потоком и помещение результата в массив номер 1, потом второй поток берет следующее число из очереди и обрабатывает его, используя предыдущее посчитанное значение потоком 1. Проблема в том, что оба потока запускаются только 1 раз.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import threading
from collections import deque
from cmath import cosh, sinh
import random as rd


def write_complex(name):
    a = -20
    b = 20
    numbers = [(rd.randint(a, b), rd.randint(a, b)) for i in range(20)]
    with open(name, 'w') as file:
        for re, im in numbers:
            file.write(f'{re}:{im}\n')


def read_complex(name: str):
    with open(name, 'r') as file:
        array = [line.strip().split(':') for line in file.readlines()]
    return deque([complex(float(re), float(im)) for re, im in array])


def f1(e, q: deque, f1_res, f2_res):
    if e.is_set():
        e.wait(0.5)
    e.set()
    res = q.pop() - f2_res[-1]
    f1_res.append(res)
    e.clear()


def f2(e, q: deque, f1_res, f2_res):
    if e.is_set():
        e.wait(0.5)
    e.set()
    res = q.pop() - f1_res[-1]
    f2_res.append(res)
    e.clear()


name = 'complex.dat'
write_complex(name)

q = read_complex(name)  # read data

res1, res2 = [], [complex(rd.randint(-20, 20), rd.randint(-20, 20))]
e = threading.Event()
t1 = threading.Thread(target=f1, args=(e, q, res1, res2))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=f2, args=(e, q, res1, res2))
t1.start()
t2.start()

print(res1)
print(res2)
```

Comment: а зачем тут 2 потока?

Comment: @eri увы, задание придумал преподаватель

Comment: похоже на reduce функцию

Comment: ну добавь while True внутрь f1  и f2

Comment: @eri в таком случае число из очереди исчезнет при первом проходе, а при попытке последующего взятия числа будет ошибка из-за пустого deque

Comment: так после старта продолжай наполнять очередь

Comment: @eri нет, так обрабатывается по очереди, а мне нужно параллельно, тем более при таком подходе первый поток использует единственное значение из res2, что неверно

Comment: у тебя эвент там - оно по любому по очереди обрабатывается

Comment: @eri в отладчике видно, что не по очереди

Comment: напиши само задание, мне кажется вы его не так поняли.

Comment: @eri я прикрепил его, в итоге у меня должно получиться два массива res1, res2, по которым я построю график